# How to update the contacts of Account when one contact is updated?

Tags: trigger, relationships, update

How to mass-update all other contact records on the same account When a single contact record updated?

**Trigger code:**

```
trigger syncContact on Contact (after update) {
    map<id,string> conMap = new map<id,string>();
    set<id> accId = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
    {
        conMap.put(c.Id,c.Title);
        accId.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
    if(recursiveCheck.runOnce() && trigger.isupdate)
    {
        for(account a : [select id,(select id,title from contacts where id not in : conMap.keySet() ) from account where id in : accId])
        {
            conList.add(a.contacts);
            for(contact c : a.contacts)
            {
             c.Title=conMap.get(id).Title;   
                conlist.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
update conlist;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to create a map of contactId vs title. You will not be able to get the title from this map in you for loop as you are excluding the contact in your query that you have put on your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    trigger syncContact on Contact (after update) {
    map<id,string> conMap = new map<id,string>();
    set<id> accId = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        conMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Title);
        accId.add(c.id);
    }
    List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
    if(recursiveCheck.runOnce() && trigger.isupdate){
        for(account a : [select id,(select id,AccountId,title from contacts where id not in : accId ) from account where id in : conMap.keySet()]){
            for(contact c : a.contacts){
                c.Title=conMap.get(c.AccountId);   
                conlist.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    update conlist;
}
```